# Creating an object in associative array if it doesn't exist, then referencing it

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to create a function which simply checks if a name input by the user exists withing an associative array, then reference that position, if not, create the object, then reference THAT position.

I though I had it, yet when my code attempts to change a value, such as `player1.ptsWin = 2;` it gives me a console error saying ptsWin is undefined.

```
function verifyPlayer1(name) {
    var foundPlayer = false;
    for (i = 0; i < player.length; i++) {
        if (player[i].name === name) {
            player1 = player[i];
            foundPlayer = true;
            break;
        }
        if (foundPlayer === false) {
            player[player.length] = {
                name: name,
                points: 0,
                ptsWin: 0,
                ptsLose: 0,
                ptsTie: 0,
                gamesWon: 0,
                gamesLost: 0,
                gamesTied: 0,
                sequence: [],
                correct: false
            };

            player1 = player[player.length - 1];

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "an associative array" --- there are no such a thing as an associative array in javascript

Comment: Seems like you have to move the `if (foundPlayer === false) {` part outside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're checking `found` *inside* your loop, which is a pretty serious logic problem.

You need to finish your loop, and then check. Also, don't bother with a second variable (`found`), just check whether `player` gets set. Also-also, don't bother with `length`, just `push` onto the array.

```
function verifyPlayer1(name) {
    var player1;
    for (i = 0; i < player.length; i++) {
        if (player[i].name === name) {
            player1 = player[i];
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!player1) {
        player1 = {
            name: name,
            points: 0,
            ptsWin: 0,
            ptsLose: 0,
            ptsTie: 0,
            gamesWon: 0,
            gamesLost: 0,
            gamesTied: 0,
            sequence: [],
            correct: false
        };
        player.push(player1)
    }

    return player1;
}
```

You also seem to be using a global (`player1`) to return your player. You shouldn't do that. Instead, return the player from the function.